# Why does yahoo.de mail mark my email as spam inspite of full score on mail-tester?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I set up an email server following https://www.makeuseof.com/make-your-own-raspberry-pi-email-server/  (It makes use of emailwiz).
I finally got a score of 10/10 on mail-tester.com.
Also, the emails goes into the normal inbox on gmail, web.de and live.com, just not yahoo.de. I have the following ideas:

1. The yahoo spam filter does not like my tld (.eu)
2. It remembered that I send emails without PTR record with the same domain name, but different tld.
3. I need to set up an unsuscribe header (the only thing mail-tester still noted).

About the last option: Do I have to do that in the settings of postfix or can I add it individually to the test email? (e.g. with "insert html" in thunderbird, and then the desired tags (<list_unsubscribe>...?). If I have to change the settings, can I make it invisible?